# how can i use jQuery's each() to implement my character count & text area toggle for sections each having its own form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dry

my page [here](http://test.usfamilyguide.com/test4/orderformpage3.php) has multiple checkboxes, each with its own textarea below. On page load, the textareas are hidden. Clicking a checkbox `toggle`s the text area, which then displays a character counter beneath.

This is working just as i need, for all the pairs of checkbox/ textarea. My problem is that in the interest of time and *showing* the client the functionality, i repeated the jQuery code for every single pair. I know there is a way to use `each` or one of its methods to use the same code for all the pairs, but i struggled making it work.

In the HTML, i did my best to use ID's and classes for all the checkboxes, textareas, wrappers for both, wrappers for each entire section, with the intention of being able to use jQuery and / or JS selectors to select anything.

If this question is not phrased well, please help me improve (i think *this* one is, but StackOverflow is giving me the warning at the top of the page about danger of being blocked.)

I will only paste in three pieces of the code that is repeated.

So, how can i not repeat the code and have the exact same functionality as i do now? I think this will use `each` and maybe changing what selectors re used, but i need help doing it!

The code snippet:

```js
 

/*
     * orderformpage3.php text area show hide and character count  
     * this code needs to use an each method to iterate instead of repeat. For now, it is repeating.
     */
    $(document).ready(function() {

          /*
           * for birthday parties
           */
          // toggle visibility of text area on checkbox click
          $("#birthdayParties").click(function() {
            // $("#birthdayPartiesInput").toggleClass("show");
            $("#birthdayPartiesWrap").toggle(500);
          });

          // Character counter
          $("#birthdayPartiesInput").on('keyup', function(e) {
            var counter, textEntered, countRemaining;
            // get the number of characters in the box
            textEntered = $("#birthdayPartiesInput").val();
            // number left = number of characters - our maximum
            var counter = (500 - (textEntered.length));
            // access the div for characters remaining
            countRemaining = $("#charactersRemainingBirthday");
            // put the number of characters left into that div
            countRemaining.text(counter + ' characters remnaining');
          });

          /*
           * for fun activities
           */
          // toggle visibility of text area on checkbox click
          $("#funActivities").click(function() {
            // $("#birthdayPartiesInput").toggleClass("show");
            $("#funActivitiesWrap").toggle(500);
          });

          // Character counter
          $("#funActivitiesInput").on('keyup', function(e) {
            var counter, textEntered, countRemaining;
            // get the number of characters in the box
            textEntered = $("#funActivitiesInput").val();
            // number left = number of characters - our maximum
            var counter = (500 - (textEntered.length));
            // access the div for characters remaining
            countRemaining = $("#charactersRemainingFunActivities");
            // put the number of characters left into that div
            countRemaining.text(counter + ' characters remnaining');
          });

          /*
           * for Summer Camps
           */
          // toggle visibility of text area on checkbox click
          $("#summerCamps").click(function() {
            // $("#birthdayPartiesInput").toggleClass("show");
            $("#summerCampsWrap").toggle(500);
          });

          // Character counter
          $("#summerCampsInput").on('keyup', function(e) {
            var counter, textEntered, countRemaining;
            // get the number of characters in the box
            textEntered = $("#summerCampsInput").val();
            // number left = number of characters - our maximum
            var counter = (500 - (textEntered.length));
            // access the div for characters remaining
            countRemaining = $("#charactersRemainingSummerCamps");
            // put the number of characters left into that div
            countRemaining.text(counter + ' characters remnaining');
          });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="category-row">
      <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name="birthdayparties" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="birthdayParties" />
        </div>
        <label for="birthdayParties" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Birthday Parties</label>
        <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="birthdayPartiesWrap">
          <textarea name="birthdaypartiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="birthdayPartiesInput">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
          <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingBirthday">500 characters remnaining</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



   <div class="category-row">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
            <?php if ($birthdayparties == true) {$birthdaypartieschecked = 'checked';} else { $birthdaypartieschecked = '';}?>


             <input type="checkbox" name="birthdayparties" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="birthdayParties" <?php echo $birthdaypartieschecked; ?>/>
           </div>
            <label for="birthdayParties" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Birthday Parties</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="birthdayPartiesWrap" >
              <textarea name="birthdaypartiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="birthdayPartiesInput"><?php echo $_SESSION['birthdaypartiesdescription']; ?></textarea>
              <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingBirthday">500 characters remnaining</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <div class="category-row">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
           <?php if ($funactivities == true) {$funactivitieschecked = 'checked';} else { $funactivitieschecked = '';}?>
             <input type="checkbox" name="funactivities" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="funActivities" <?php echo $funactivitieschecked; ?>/>
           </div>
            <label for="funActivities" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Fun Activities</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="funActivitiesWrap">
              <textarea name="funactivitiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="funActivitiesInput"><?php echo $_SESSION['sessfunactivitiesdescription']; ?></textarea>
              <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingFunActivities">500 characters remnaining</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="category-row">
          <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
           <?php if ($summercamps == true) {
    $summercampschecked = 'checked';
    echo '<script>';
    echo '$("#summerCampsWrap").toggle(100);';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    $summercampschecked = '';
    echo '<script>';
    echo '$("#summerCampsWrap").toggle(100);';
    echo '</script>';
}
?>




  <input type="checkbox" name="summercamps" class="col-form-label
form-control category-checkbox" id="summerCamps" <?php echo
    $summercampschecked; ?>/>
           </div>
            <label for="summerCamps" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Summer Camps</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="summerCampsWrap">
              <textarea name="summercampsdescription" type="text"  class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="summerCampsInput"><?php echo $_SESSION['sesssummercampsdescription']; ?></textarea>
              <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingSummerCamps">500 characters remnaining</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to rely on `id` so you might make your code more abstract.
You might use `this` as a reference to the current element and then traverse DOM using `next`, `closest`, `parent`, `find` etc.

Here you are:

```js
/*
 * orderformpage3.php text area show hide and character count  
 * this code needs to use an each method to iterate instead of repeat. For now, it is repeating.
 */
$(document).ready(function() {

  // toggle visibility of text area on checkbox click
  $(".category-checkbox").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".category-row")
      .find('.description-wrap').toggle(500)
      .find('textarea').keyup();
  });

  // Character counter
  $(".category-text").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var counter, textEntered, countRemaining;
    textEntered = $(this).val();
    var counter = (500 - (textEntered.length));
    $(this).next(".charactersRemaining")
      .text(counter + ' characters remnaining');
  });

});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="category-row">
  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="birthdayparties" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="birthdayParties" />
    </div>
    <label for="birthdayParties" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Birthday Parties</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="birthdayPartiesWrap">
      <textarea name="birthdaypartiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="birthdayPartiesInput">birthday parties description</textarea>
      <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingBirthday">500 characters remnaining</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="category-row">
  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="funactivities" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="funActivities" />
    </div>
    <label for="funActivities" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Fun Activities</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="funActivitiesWrap">
      <textarea name="funactivitiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="funActivitiesInput">sess fun activities description</textarea>
      <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingFunActivities">500 characters remnaining</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="category-row">
  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="summercamps" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="summerCamps" />
    </div>
    <label for="summerCamps" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Summer Camps</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="summerCampsWrap">
      <textarea name="summercampsdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="summerCampsInput"> sess summer camps description</textarea>
      <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingSummerCamps">500 characters remnaining</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

You probably face the issue when your checkbox is checked, but the textarea is hidden. To solve it you need to update your code to set class `.hide` like this:

```
<div class="category-row">
  <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
      <?php if ($birthdayparties == true) {$birthdaypartieschecked = 'checked';} else {$birthdaypartieschecked = '';} ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="birthdayparties" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="birthdayParties" <?php echo $birthdaypartieschecked; ?>/>
    </div>
    <label for="birthdayParties" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Birthday Parties</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap <?php echo ($birthdayparties ? '' : 'hide'); ?>" id="birthdayPartiesWrap">
      <textarea name="birthdaypartiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="birthdayPartiesInput"><?php echo $_SESSION['birthdaypartiesdescription']; ?></textarea>
      <div class="charactersRemaining" id="charactersRemainingBirthday">500 characters remnaining</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers which explain changes to code are upvoted more often than those that just spoon-feed the correct code to the OP.

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly, and first time i've seen `closest`. Very nice.

Comment: @bluedimensional, happy to help.

Comment: I have another issue which is directly related here, can i ask it right here, is that good practice? Or do i edit the OP? There are session variables setting the checkbox to checked on page load, but textarea is hidden. From there it's inverted. I've tried many things with no success - embedding JS in the `php else if` (which i can edit into OP) with no success.

Comment: @bluedimensional, usually another problem requires another question, but in this case the problem is not so big.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @KoshVery got it, and thanks again! that worked perfectly and helped my day be even smoother. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to improve the jquery. this way you will only write the jquery once. however, to do so i need to change "#charactersRemainingBirthday" to "#birthdayPartiesInputRemaining" check out my snippet.

hopefully i t can help you in some way.

have a nice day!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".category-checkbox").click(function(){
        $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Wrap").toggle(500);
    });

    $(".category-text").on('keyup', function(e){
        var counter, textEntered, countRemaining;
        textEntered = $(this).val();
        var counter = (500 - (textEntered.length));
        countRemaining = $("#"+$(this).attr('id')+"Remaining");
        countRemaining.text(counter + ' characters remnaining');
    });
})
```

```css
.hide{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category-row">
 <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="birthdayparties" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="birthdayParties" />
  </div>
  <label for="birthdayParties" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Birthday Parties</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="birthdayPartiesWrap" >
   <textarea name="birthdaypartiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="birthdayPartiesInput"></textarea>
   <div class="charactersRemaining" id="birthdayPartiesInputRemaining">500 characters remnaining</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="category-row">
 <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="funactivities" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="funActivities" />
  </div>
  <label for="funActivities" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Fun Activities</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="funActivitiesWrap">
   <textarea name="funactivitiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="funActivitiesInput"></textarea>
   <div class="charactersRemaining" id="funActivitiesInputRemaining">500 characters remnaining</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="category-row">
 <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-xs-1 ml-3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="otheractivities" class="col-form-label form-control category-checkbox" id="otherActivities" />
  </div>
  <label for="otherActivities" class="col-xs-3 ml-2 col-form-label">Other Activities</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12 description-wrap hide" id="otherActivitiesWrap">
   <textarea name="otheractivitiesdescription" type="text" class="form-control col-form-label category-text" id="otherActivitiesInput"></textarea>
   <div class="charactersRemaining" id="otherActivitiesInputRemaining">500 characters remnaining</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```